# Oracle SQL Developer spool output?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Oracle SQL Developer 2.1.1.64 to spool the results of a query to a text file
Here is what I am running to call the quesry and spool the results

```
SET NEWPAGE 0
SET SPACE 0
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET FEEDBACK OFF
SET HEADING OFF
set verify off
SET ECHO OFF
spool c:\client\output_sql\t_1001_02_0522_.txt
@c:\client\queries\t_1001_02_query;
spool off
```

Unfortunately,  i am getting

> @c:\client\queries\t_1001_02_query

at the top of my output text file and I need to have just the results.
I have searched the web for this and have tried a variety of things like:
set verify off
set termout off

Comment: If you add `SET TERMOUT OFF` then what you have here should behave in SQLPlus. Do you have the option to use that instead of SQL Developer? Also note that when I do this (in SQLPlus) I usually start with `SET ECHO OFF` then `SET TERMOUT OFF`, but I don't know if that actually makes a difference.

Comment: I do not have SQLPlus.  When I run those commands I get a skipped error.  Thanks though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that if I save my query(spool_script_file.sql) and call it  using this

@c:\client\queries\spool_script_file.sql as script(F5)

My output now is just the results with out the commands at the top.

I found this solution on the oracle forums.

Answer (score 9):

For Spooling in Oracle SQL Developer, here is the solution.

set heading on

set linesize 1500

set colsep '|'

set numformat 99999999999999999999

set pagesize 25000

spool E:\abc.txt

@E:\abc.sql;

spool off

The hint is :

1. when we spool from sql plus , then the whole query is required.
2. when we spool from Oracle Sql Developer , then the reference path of the query required as given in the specified example.

Answer (score 1):

Another way simpler than me has worked with SQL Developer 4 in Windows 7

```
spool "path_to_file\\filename.txt"
query to execute
spool of
```

**You have to execute it as a script, because if not only the query will be saved in the output file**
In the path name I use the double character "\" as a separator when working with Windows and SQL,
The output file will display the query and the result.

Comment: But as I stated, I only need the results, nothing else in the output file.

Answer (score 0):

You can export the query results to a text file (or insert statements, or even pdf) by right-clicking on Query Result row (any row) and choose Export

using Sql Developer 3.0

See [SQL Developer downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html) for latest versions

Comment: I know, but I would like to get the same result with out the manual export, since I have over 100 queries to run.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm not specifying a path, I did a search for my spool file in **Windows 10** and I found it on the following location:

```
C:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Roaming
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the command window option.
provide the full path of the spool file prefix with `@` symbol and hit enter.
The script execution will be taken care of and displayed in the status of the queries executed.

ex.

```
sql>@"mention spool file path"
sql>@"D:\test.txt"
```

Answer (score -1):

I was trying things to duplicate the spools you get from sqlplus.
I found the following and hope it helps:

Create your sql script file ie:

Please note the echo and serveroutput.

Test_Spool.SQL

```
Spool 'c:\temp\Test1.txt';
set echo on;
set serveroutput on;
declare
sqlresult varchar2(60);

begin
  select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') into sqlresult from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('The date is ' || sqlresult);
end;

/

Spool off;
set serveroutput off;
set echo off;
```

Run the script from another worksheet:

```
@TEST_Spool.SQL
```

My output from the Test1.txt

```
set serveroutput on
declare
sqlresult varchar2(60);

begin
  select to_char(sysdate,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') into sqlresult from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('The date is ' || sqlresult);
end;
```

anonymous block completed

The date is 2016-04-07 09:21:32

Spool of